# Why I get `Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ...` error?

Tags: perl, runtime-error

In my program I get error:

```
$ perl -e 'print $i +0'
Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at -e line 1.
```

But next two works fine:

```
$ perl -e 'print $i'
$ perl -e 'print 0 +$i'
0
```

**What is wrong with first case?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The statement `print $i +0` is different because `$i` is potentially a valid file handle. But when perl tries to use it as one it fails because it is `undef`

The precise rules that perl uses to determine whether you are trying to use a file handle are arcane, but simply removing the space after `$i` thwarts this interpretation and prints the expression `$i+0` instead

Comment: ah, `Indirect object call`. I missed that.

Comment: No, it's not an indirect object call in this case because `print` is not a method. It's simply an optional first parameter.

Comment: @Borodin That's true enough but it's the very same underlying parsing rules that apply here which also allow for the invocant in the so-called "indirect object" method-dispatch syntax.